# How to smoothly mix material on edges of said materials?

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm somewhat new to blender and i have a problem with mixing materials:

Material A and B are similar (roughness, and colors) but material B has "holes" in it.[image: places where materials A and B need mixing] These holes need to be in specific location on that mesh, and only there.

I need to somehow mix thesee materials so that is transformes smoothly to one another, and i dont know how.

I thought about "merging" them and mixing them with gradient texture as a factor but given that the materials are messy, and they blend in multiple places i don't think it can work, or at least i don't know can it work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you actually tried merging them with the gradient method you have mentioned? I think it is a great idea.

Comment: @EricXue i just tried but the way it worked it applied the "new mixed material" to the whole mesh, and it blended it smoothly, however it blended it in one place (with Mapping node i can chose the place where it blends) and i need it to blend several times; 
In the photo i added above with the main question there are two places where blending should take place (places where A ends/starts and where B starts/ends).

Im not sure how to set up gradient texture that blends in two (or more) places, and how to control these places

Comment: Cool, I think I found a way. I will be writing in an answer soon.